# how to name an uploaded file in zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have a form that contains and form of which code goes like this for image

```
$image->setDestination(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../public/images/upload');
```

and in my controller i have

```
if($countryForm->image->isUploaded())
{ 
  $countryForm->image->receive();    
  $countryModel->addCountry(
    $countryForm->getValue('name'), 
    $countryForm->getValue('description'),
    $this->view->baseUrl('/images/upload/'.basename($countryForm->image->getFileName()))
  );
}
```

how can i change the name of the filename uploaded. I want to set it to

```
random(100).time().ext
```

trying this code

```
 if($form->image->isUploaded()){
   $upload = new Zend_File_Transfer();
   $upload->addFilter('Rename', array('target' => APPLICATION_PATH.'/../images/upload/'.time().'.jpg', 'overwrite' => true));
   $form->image->receive();
   $filename = $form->image->getFilename(); 
   $pageModel->addPage($form->getValue('pagetitle'),
   $form->getValue('pagemetakeyword'),
   $form->getValue('pagemetadescription'),
   $form->getValue('pagecategory'),
   $filename,
   $form->getValue('pagecontent'),
   $form->getValue('pagestatus')
  );   

}
```

would still give  'backend/public/images/upload/picture.jpg' in my database

I have in my form the following code

```
 $image = $this->createElement('file', 'image'); 
 $image->setLabel('Image: '); 
 $image->setRequired(FALSE); 
 $image->setDestination(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../public/images/upload/'); 
 $image->addValidator('Count', false, 1); 
 $image->addValidator('Size', false, 1024000); 
 $image->addValidator('Extension', false, 'jpg,jpeg,png,gif'); 
 $this->addElement($image);
```

and i am using Ubuntu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use addFilter()

http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.file.transfer.filters.html#zend.file.transfer.filters.usage

If you include the filename (here you can use your rand() function) and add it to the `target` array value it will rename it

From documentation:

```
$upload = new Zend_File_Transfer();

// Set a new destination path
$upload->addFilter('Rename', 'C:\picture\uploads');

// Set a new destination path and overwrites existing files
$upload->addFilter('Rename', array('target' => 'C:\picture\uploads', 'overwrite' => true));
```

Try:

```
    if($form->image->isUploaded()){
       $upload = new Zend_File_Transfer();
       $files = $upload->getFileInfo();
       //You should also add file validation, see:
 //http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.file.transfer.introduction.html#zend.file.transfer.introduction.checking
       $upload->addFilter('Rename', APPLICATION_PATH.'/../images/upload/'.time().'.jpg', $files[0]);
       $upload->receive($files[0]);
       $filename = $files[0]->getFilename(); 
       $pageModel->addPage($form->getValue('pagetitle'),
       $form->getValue('pagemetakeyword'),
       $form->getValue('pagemetadescription'),
       $form->getValue('pagecategory'),
       $filename,
       $form->getValue('pagecontent'),
       $form->getValue('pagestatus')
      );
```

Comment: where to do this?? in the form??

Comment: after isUploaded() if, before receive()

Comment: and array('target' => 'C:\picture\uploads')?? can i add filename as array('target' => 'C:\picture\uploads'.$filename)??

Comment: Yes target can have a filename

Comment: this is not working! Please see the changes above. And thanks to you previous help

Comment: getFileInfo() returns an array, so $files[0]->getFilename(); does not work (it's not an object). It's best to create your unique filename for changing it, so you have it for saving in your model or whatever.

Answer (score 5):

In your form class add the element like this:

```
$fileDestination = realpath(APPLICATION_PATH.'/../images/upload/');
$this->addElement('file','cover', array(
    'label'       => 'Cover:',
    'required'    => false,
    'destination' => $fileDestination,
    'validators'  => array(
        array('Count', false, array(1)),
        array('Size', false, array(1048576 * 5)),
        array('Extension', false, array('jpg,png,gif')),
    ),
    'decorators'  => $this->_elementDecorator
));
```

In you controller:

```
$originalFilename = pathinfo($form->image->getFileName());
$newName = rand(1,100) . time() . $originalFilename['extension'];
$form->cover->addFilter('Rename', $newName);
$data = $form->getValues();
```

Comment: Need an additional dot in between name & extension. $newName = rand(1,100) . time() .'.'. $originalFilename['extension'];